# Do Our Thoughts come from the Cosmos?

Tags: atma, spirituality, mind, cosmology

I have been learning more about the nature of the mind, pranayama and, in general, the Hindu view of reality. One thing I’ve really been exploring as of late is this idea that we are not our thoughts or feelings, and that those are the sensations of the body or mind and not the Atma (me), which instead experiences them. I also read the following on another website discussing the same, but it said this:

“You receive thoughts/feelings, from the universal consciousness/cosmos, that are aligned with the frequency/vibration you are currently in. You act as a receiver of these thoughts/feelings. You are a soul, the pure consciousness, observing these thoughts in a physical body and your ultimate goal is to align yourself and identify with the thoughts/feelings that will raise your vibration and help you progress in your journey.”

My question is if that statement is compatible or aligned way of thinking in Hinduism? Also, teachings I am learning seem to be general and not very sect-specific, but I guess I have been referencing Saiva Siddhanta sources for information, where possible if that’s relevant.

Comment: This is a poor amalgamation conflating different Hindu philosophical concepts. It is 'New Age' philosophy, not Hindu. Your thoughts are part of your individual physical consciousness. You control your own destiny and karma. Please read the forum guidelines. This is not a forum to compare non Hindu beliefs with Hinduism.

Comment: our thoughts come from idea, ie, unfinished idea. this is the same as bound to desire.   then all ideas as like jain ppl say, asrava, an influx of karma